# C#/Selenium .Net conversion ro .Core error

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core

I am currently converting C#/Selenium test suites from .NET to .NET Core

Prior to conversion this little bit of code worked fine in one suite.

```
public void ClearConsoleErrors()
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
    String script = "console.clear();";
    js.ExecuteScript(script);
    Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
}
```

Now we get this error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

The error happens on this line - `Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);`

And ideas folks?

Comment: As ever with NullReferenceException, I'd start off by finding which reference is null. Is it `js`? Or the result of `Driver.Manage()`? Or the result of `Driver.Manage().Logs`?

Comment: Which line is it?

Comment: The error happens on this line - Driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);

Comment: Can you add more code to show where/how driver is created and how this method is expected to access it?

Comment: Which version of browser and web driver are you using?

Comment: Hi, Chrome  87.0.4280.66 with matching Driver